# Meteor: Verify Email Link is Logging User Out

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In my Meteor app, I have a signup form at `/signup` that requires a username, password, and email. Upon submission of this form, the user is automatically logged in to the site via `Accounts.createUser()` and an email verification message is sent to the user's email address via `Accounts.config({sendVerificationEmail: true})`.

Like I said, the user is automatically logged in at this point but with an un-verified email address. The issue is that once the user clicks the email verification link from the email, they are directed to `/verify-email/:token` (e.g. http://domain.com/#/verify-email/35_7bRc_kXyUfRnlB7LB9NFGUyEDPH8E8pTPXKeDBY6), which redirects to `/`, and somewhere in this process the user becomes LOGGED OUT. `Meteor.user()` returns `null`, so I can't verify the email address until they manually sign in again (and I can then handle the token).

Why is the user logged out by following this link? I notice that by simply refreshing the page after redirection to `/`, the user becomes logged back in (without having to re-enter credentials). Here's my iron-router file if it helps:

```
/* Declare global router configurations */
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  notFoundTemplate: 'noData',
});

/* Prevent templates from rendering before data is ready */
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {
  if (!this.ready()) {
    pause();
  }
});

/* Define routes */
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
  });
  this.route('signup', {
  });
  this.route('login', {
  });
  this.route('forgot', {
  });
  this.route('ohlc', {
    progress: {
      enabled: true
    },
    controller: 'ohlcController'
  });
  //this.route('kitchensink', {});
  this.route('404', {
    path: '/*'
  });
});
```

Do I need additional paths/configuration to handle `/verify-email/:token`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue thread solved my problem: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/3

Seems to be a known issue with iron-router, but that thread has a workaround.